# Notice : Undefined index in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, undefined

**My data is getting saved in database but show the following notice:**

> Notice: Undefined index: fname in D:\xampp\htdocs\savedata\saa.php on
>   line 20
>
> Notice: Undefined index: lname in D:\xampp\htdocs\savedata\saa.php on
>   line 20
>
> 1 record added

**This is validation code:**

```
    <?php
    $firstname=$lastname="";
    $firstnameErr=$lastnameErr="";
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST") {
       $valid = true; //Your indicator for your condition, actually it depends on what you need. I am just used to this method.
     if(empty($_POST["fname"]))
    {
        $firstnameErr="*Name is Required";
        $valid=false;
    }
    else
    {
    $firstname=test_input($POST["fname"]);  
    }  

    if(empty($_POST["lname"]))
    {
        $lastnameErr="*Name is Required";
        $valid=false;
    }
    else
    {
    $$lastname=test_input($POST["lname"]);  
    }  

     //if valid then redirect
      if($valid){

          echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=saa.php">';    
        exit;
    //   header('Location: datasubmitted.php');
    //   exit();
      }
    }
    // Sanitize data
    function test_input($data) {
       $data = trim($data);
       $data = stripslashes($data);
       $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
       return $data;
    }
    ?>
```

**html form code**

```
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
    Firstname: <input type="text" name="fname" /><?php echo $firstnameErr;?><br />
    Lastname: <input type="text" name="lname" /><?php echo $lastnameErr?>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

**code to insert data in database**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","geetha@99");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("test", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO nametable (firstname,lastname)
VALUES
('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Comment: `$POST["fname"]` is your error in validation script, `$_POST["fname"]` is correct.

Comment: Agreed @АндрейПочекуев

Comment: @АндрейПочекуев : good catch..but wouldn't it throw a `error`, rather than a warning!! :)

Comment: Why would it? It looks for empty array `$POST`, sees that its indexes `"fname"` and `"lname"` are empty and raises a notice. `$$lastname` would raise an error though, because it would try to use empty variable name but the code never gets to that part.

Answer (score 2):

Its a notice; not an error

To fix this, you'll have to check whether `$_POST['fname']` and `$_POST['lname']` are set:

```
if(!isset($_POST["fname"] && empty($_POST["fname"])) {
   ...
}

if(!isset($_POST["lname"] && empty($_POST["lname"])) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its happening because your `fname` variable is not set in`POST` when its checking for the condition.....so `$_POST["fname"]` is empty and hence its throws `undefined` warning

**use it this way:**

```
if(isset($_POST["fname"]) && !empty($_POST["fname"]))
{
   /* execution part*/
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `!empty(...)`

Answer (score 1):

For validation on an array element do not use empty but use array_key_exists

Your validation could be

```
if(array_key_exists('lname', $_POST) && empty($_POST["lname"]))
{
    $lastnameErr="*Name is Required";
    $valid=false;
}
```

Or you should to get the element with the filter_input function. This is the preferred method

```
$lname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lname');

if (empty($lname)) {
    $lastnameErr="*Name is Required";
    $valid=false;
}
```

For the insertion of the element I discourage to use the $_POST variable into a query, but to replace with an escape version of this.

You could put this check into the validation

```
$lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $lname);
```

Another note: Do not use mysql_ functions because they are deprecated. You must use the mysqli_ extensions.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

You have several typos in your script. First one

```
 $firstname=test_input($POST["fname"]);
```

should be

```
 $firstname=test_input($_POST["fname"]);
```

second one contains two

```
 $$lastname=test_input($POST["lname"]);
```

should be

```
 $lastname = test_input($_POST["lname"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**, using `$_POST` variables directly in your queries will make your code insecure, due to mysql inject danger. At least use `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['var'])` if not PDO with bindparams.

**Second**, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Regarding your **erorr message**, it would help to actually let us know what line is line 20.

Regardless, you error is because you are using something like `$_POST[fname]` without testing if `$_POST[fname]` exists. Also, use `$_POST['fname']` not `$_POST[fname]`.

```
$p_fname = '';
if (isset($_POST['fname'])) $p_fname = $_POST['fname'];
//then
$sql = "INSERT ..... SET field='".mysql_real_escape_string($p_fname)."'";
```

And if you don't care about the E_NOTICE level errors, you just put

```
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE); //at the top of your scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

you can ignore this notice by using this conditions on top of page,

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['fname']) && $_POST['fname']!=''){ $firstname=$_POST['fname'];}else{$firstname='';}
if(isset($_POST['lname']) && $_POST['lname']!=''){ $lastname=$_POST['lname'];}else{$lastname='';}
?>
```

and use `$firstname` and `$lastname` instread of `$_POST[fname]`and `$_POST['lname']`.